# how to create derived attribute inside view

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm creating a view for **assessment** entity in SQL Oracle and I created a derived attribute **result** inside it I tried this code but it's not working.

the assessment is the super-entity for three sub-entities which are diagnostic and summative and formative that is why I'm creating a view for it `assessment = diagnostic + summative + formative`.

the result will include the calculation of score attributes from the previous three entities.

this is for Oracle SQL developer

create view assessment as

```
select asses_num ,d_score ,asses_type ,student_ID from diagnostic
union 
select asses_num ,s_score ,asses_type ,student_ID from summative
union
select asses_num ,f_score ,asses_type ,student_ID from formative
union
select (d_score+s_score+f_score) as result from diagnostic, summative, formative ;
```

I expect to have the view created including result as derived attribute.but, I have error "query block has incorrect number of result columns"

Comment: Your last query "union select (d_score+s_score+f_score) as result from diagnostic, summative, formative" is not correct. With union you have to provide the exact number of columns in each Select

Comment: Please add some sample data to your question.

Comment: thank you so much for your help, but I did not have sample data yet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> "query block has incorrect number of result columns"

You get ORA-01789 because all the subqueries in a UNION statement must have the same projection (number of columns, matching datatypes). Your last subquery has a different projection from the other subqueries.

It's not clear why you're trying to solve your problem with UNION anyway. It might make more sense to use regular joins:

```
create view assessment as 
    select d.asses_num 
           , d.student_ID
           , d.d_score as diagnostic_score
           , s.s_score as summative_score
           , f.f_score as formative_score
           , (d.d_score + s.s_score + f.f_score) as result 
    from diagnostic d
         join summative s 
              on d.asses_num = s.asses_num
              and d.student_ID = s.student_ID
          join formative f 
              on d.asses_num = f.asses_num
              and d.student_ID = f.student_ID
;
```

My assumptions (in the absence of sample data and structures):

- records exist in all three tables, so we need inner joins rather than outer joins
- ASSESS_TYPE is not a join criterion because it defines the subtype of the sub-entities

If these are not correct or you have additional requirements please **edit your question** to include clarifying details.